# Can Site Templates be updated in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-template, update

I`ve created a published site in SharePoint 2013 using a customized Site Template (name: abc.wsp) and its working fine.
As per additional business requirement, need to update the existing site template (name: abc.wsp) and add few SharePoint 2013 based Lists.

Please confirm if its possible to update the existing template?
If yes, will it update the published sites already created using the existing template with the new lists updated to the template?

If not, any alternate that would allow to update all sites (created using a template) at once with additional lists?

Any pointer will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you customized using save as template method then you cant update the existing sites to get new changes. This will only work with the new site collection created on that template.

But if you develop it using the solution, then you have to update the existing solution to reflect the changes to existing sites.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/bf8a3977-88ca-49da-8b98-6a8233bd901b/updatedelete-custom-site-templatessolutions-or-listlibrary-templates?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 1):

A site template is a package that contains a set of differences from a base site definition. Site templates let you use a browser to easily create a template site from an existing SharePoint site. The site, including pages, lists, libraries, and contents, is archived into a single .stp file.

**Site Template Pros.** Site templates enable administrators to create predefined sites to simplify site provisioning from a user perspective. Sites that are created with them are consistent, which improves usability and maintenance. The pages are stored in just one location—the content database.

**Site Template Cons.** Because the pages are stored in the content database, performance degradation could occur. Once you create and save a template, **you can't update it,** which might lead to future product compatibility issues.

*The another option is that, You should use **Site Definition***

**Site Definition Pros.** Administrators must programmatically create site definitions, giving them more control over site creation. Sites can be provisioned easily—users don’t have to customize them. Site definitions provide greater control over a site's look and feel. Because sites are more consistent, there are fewer user support calls for help.

**Site Definition Cons.** Creating site definitions requires programming skills (i.e., Visual Studio). Site definitions are costly to maintain. The definition files are stored on each WFE server; therefore, updates must follow change control management processes when multiple WFE servers are involved.